# Is the use of the construct "loss in" acceptable in the following context?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, science, academia

Is the use of the construct *loss in* acceptable in this context?

> Symptoms of stroke include loss in sensory perception

According to Grammarly, *'loss in'* should be replaced with *'loss of'*. But there are various instances where such a construct is used in practice.

> Examples:
>
> - ...to compensate for the *loss in* perception through the multi-sensory-integration ...
>   ([phys.org](http://phys.org/news/2016-08-device-foods-fat-sugar-salt.html))
> - University of Florida study reveals *loss in* sensory perception may not be linked to aging 
>   ([ScienceDaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/1997/09/970912133938.htm?trendmd-shared=0))
> - Furthermore, normal aging appears to be associated with *loss in* sensory functioning...
>   ([Springer](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12078-011-9102-8))

This construct seems to by widely accepted in the scientific community. I'm not sure why Grammarly would flag this as a critical issue. What is an expert's take on this?

Comment: *loss of* means complete loss of all sensory perception.  *loss in* means some degradation of sensory perception.

Comment: @Jim  How about in the use of the phrase "loss of pay"? I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean losing all of the salary at once.

Comment: Mass nouns like, *pay, milk, money* etc behave a little different.

Comment: In essence, the usage differs between *qualitative* terms, such as 'perception', and *quantitative* terms like 'pay'. Is this what you meant, @Jim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two originating phrases are "a loss of" and "a loss in".  The latter is used normally with partial losses, while the former tends to be for complete losses.  (Jim did comment on this briefly above.)

> It's not a demotion to switch jobs, but it might be a loss in income.
> She wanted to stay home with the baby, but her loss of income for the family would be too great.
>
> My job involved daily use of headphones: a guaranteed loss in hearing.
> The explosion blinded him temporarily, but caused a permanent loss of hearing.

Of course, people will say anything colloquially...the English language has suffered some unfortunate losses in quality...

Answer (score 0):

It is needless to mention, though there is no harm in mentioning, that "in" is used to refer to a position inside and 'of' has a strong sense of possession or ownership. LOSS  goes to mean wanting in or total absence of something. Arguably it can be said that LOSS has no such prepositions that can be termed appropriate to it . Yet 'loss' is mostly used in the accompaniment of 'OF' and one may come across numerous occasions where by using graded or qualifying adjectives before 'LOSS' (Considerable, gradual or immense etc.) the same meaning is conveyed using OF as well.

However the sensory perceptions of medical terminology permeate our beings. Their impairment, decaying or degradation can equally be expressed using IN wherever required without flouting the rule for which we are supposed to use IN . We don't find fault with the expressions in the post.